# Creating multiple divs with dynamic content using JS

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'm working on trying to create multiple divs that each have an img inside.

My JS currently looks like this:

```js
for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {

  // img string
  var string = 'http://cdn.iammatthias.com/gal/mobile/mobile-9.jpg';

  // Create frame
  var gal = document.createElement('div');
  gal.id = "frame";
  document.getElementById('gal').appendChild(gal);


  document.getElementById("frame").style.background = "url('" + string + "') no-repeat center";
  document.getElementById("frame").style.backgroundBlendMode = "multiply";
  document.getElementById("frame").style.backgroundSize = "cover";

  // Create main
  var main = document.createElement('img');
  main.id = "main";
  document.getElementById('frame').appendChild(main);

  document.getElementById("main").src = string;
}
```

This gives me 10 divs with id=frame, but it stacks all the img's in the first id=frame div.

I have a JS fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/matthiaskjordan/yap7w1vn/

I was able to get it to work with EJS, but I want to have a pure JS implementation. But this is what I'm hoping to make this look like: http://imgframe.surge.sh/harp-ejs

Here is what my EJS code looks like:

```html
<% var keys = new Array(10)
    .join().split(',')
    .map(function(item, index){ return ++index;});
    for (var i=0; i<keys.length;i++) { %>
      <div id="frame" style="background: url(http://cdn.iammatthias.com/gal/mobile/mobile-<%= [keys[i]] %>.jpg); background-repeat: none; background-position: center; background-blend-mode: color-dodge;" >
       <img class="main" src="http://cdn.iammatthias.com/gal/mobile/mobile-<%= keys[i] %>.jpg" />
      </div>
<% } %>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: ID has to be a unique attribute.  If they are all getting the id of "frame" it the first one will be found.  Maybe call it "frame" + x

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yap7w1vn/3/ <-- this puts them in different frames

Comment: @ScottFanetti thanks! I tweaked it a bit to this --> https://jsfiddle.net/matthiaskjordan/yap7w1vn/1/

Moving in the right direction, thank you so much!

Comment: Just FYI - I would watch using ids in selectors.  Since they have to be unique they can be problematic and they are probably better handled dynamically.  In your gallery you can probably just add some semantic tags to the image containers like class="image-container" and user ".image-container" as a selector to access the lot of them.  

IDs are individual though.

Comment: @ScottFanetti I'll keep that in mind for the future. But for now, I have this working! Thanks for your help.

https://jsfiddle.net/matthiaskjordan/yap7w1vn/5/